# EMC Filtering for BuckBoost LED driver

Tags: emc, led-driver

I'm designing a Buck boost LED driver using the ZXLD1370 IC. the circuit works but as one engineer said ("its easy to design a circuit but difficult to get it to pass EMC).
This is where my problem is. I am testing to the EN60945 standard. 
according to the standard, the limit is 50 dBu from 150 kHz.

When doing a conducted test, the peak is at the switching frequency. I added a Common mode choke and Pi-filter to get it to 47 dBu, but I want to get it down to approx. 44 dBu so that there is enough room for proper EMC testing. I am attaching my filter design and EMC reading for your information.

I believe this is common mode noise. How would I go about to choose a suitable choke? Right now, I'm using a WE-SL5 (744272471) choke.
am I right in thinking that because of the switcher frequency (350 kHz-500 kHz)

My question is: Do I need to choose a choke that has a high impedance at this frequency range?

[image: High power LED EMC]

[image: Low Power LED EMC]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTSAx4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you spread out the spectrum? Dithering it? Even just doing something at the ADJ pin that moves the frequency between just two values (at say 1 kHz rate) alone might be enough. Doesn't have to be that much change. A little extra complexity, though.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the two pictures i.e. what are they representing circuit-wise?

Comment: Can you locate the ringing/oscillation and capture it at the source?

Comment: @jonk No I cannot spread the spectrum. the controller has a standard frequency control circuit and cannot be programmed.
P.S. which ADJ pin are you talking about?

Comment: @Andy aka
Basically I have the system designed so that the Lights can be run in two modes. (high current and Low current).
The top pic is the EMC spectrum readout of the high current setting @ 24VDC.
the bottom pic is the EMC spectrum readout of the low current setting @ 24VDC

Comment: @winny
I haven't tested this out properly. will look into it.

In the meantime, if anyone has any ideas, then please let me know. 
I am going to try and replace the current choke to a higher spec one (Wurth 744290152) - whose Common mode characteristics cover the frequencies I am interested in.

Comment: @LabMat I was thinking of a simple circuit to change the voltage between two values at the ADJ pin at a frequency of about 1 kHz.

Comment: Im sorry @jonk but I still don't understand what you are suggesting. 
the LED driver circuit as it is right now cannot be changed and it works fine. the only issue is getting it to pass EMC. 
the reason why I know the noise is common mode is that on the EMC test setup I have here, I connected a circuit that removes Differential mode noise and only allows common mode noise. The common mode noise seen on the analyser has the same frequency components and is much higher (2-3dB).

Comment: As you can all see the noise frequency, How do I choose the correct common mode choke and the capacitors C2 & C3 in the schematic?

Comment: @LabMat I know what you are trying to achieve and I was suggesting an idea that's worked in the past as a quick fix for passing EMC. But if you don't understand the concept, I'd have to write up an answer. And I'm not at that point. So I think you should continue looking for the solution approach you do understand well. I'm not interested in that aspect, though.

Comment: @jonk 
Am I right in thinking that you are suggesting to connect a circuit to pin1 of the IC (ADJ) to control the frequency? If so, then I am doing something like this currently. 
The product can function in two modes. and I just set a jumper pin that applies a set voltage at the ADJ pin. the adj pin is connected to a voltage divider that sets the voltage at the ADJ pin.

Comment: @LabMat Not sure. I'm suggesting that you dither your operating frequency, at perhaps 1 kHz, ping-ponging rapidly between two nearby frequencies of operation. Say, 401 kHz and 439 kHz, just to pick two. If you use 401 kHz for half-time and 439 kHz for the other half, that may spread the energy into two places instead of one. The frequency is controllable, if my quick scan of the datasheet managed to inform me correctly. You could select more nearby frequencies. I'm just tossing out two specific frequencies for illustration only.